# Turtlebot service installer problem & bug?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I have installed Turtlebot iso file provided from the Turtlebot tutorials.
However, there is no service called "turtlebot" in /etc/init.d folder.
Furthermore, the install.bash file in /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/upstart scripte seems have a bug.

In the line 22, it actually install turtlebot-start script to /usr/sbin
but, in the line 23, it gives execution permission to /usr/bin/turtlebot-start.

Which one is right? and why turtlebot iso file does not have a service file by default? why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11497/turtlebot-service-installer-problem-&-bug?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/usr/sbin/turtlebot-start is correct, could you file a ticket on the [turtlebot trac](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/newticket?component=turtlebot&type=defect&&turtlebot)

The iso should come with the service by default, however depending on the machine the wireless interface comes up with different names which we cannot control.  Thus we have the user run the install script parameterized by the network interface they want to use.  This also helps the the user be aware of the service.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2011-10-12**:
In tutorial, there is a command that "service turtlebot start". But why the turtlebot service script is not exist? Turtlebot iso file does not include it. i know upstart is for starting turtlebot service in boot period. But what if I want to stop turtlebot service, howw can I do it?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-11**:
Things in /etc/init are used for upstart. Things in /etc/init.d are used for init rc process management.  You definitely don't want both.

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2011-10-11**:
How can I use latest version? Do I need to compile it?

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2011-10-11**:
Hi. The "turtlebot.conf" file exist in /etc/init However, there is no script on /etc/init.d

In Google, there are mentions about upstart. I think turtlebot.conf file is related to upstart. But for the service, I think there should be turtlebot script file in /etc/init.d

Is this correct?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-10-11**:
This is fixed in trunk, just not in debs.